# Change from math random to window.crypto

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I use a random word generator, which I wanted to change from `math.random` to the more secure `window.crypto`.

I tried for hours to get this working and I'm sure there is a error in the code. How must I change my code to get this code to using the `window.crypto` method?

```js
var wordings = ['X',
  'I',
  'II'
];

function getRandom(randArray) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * randArray.length);
}

function showrandom() {
  document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = wordings[getRandom(wordings)] + ' ' + wordings[getRandom(wordings)];
}

showrandom();
```

What I tried so far:

```js
var wordings = ['X',
  'I',
  'II'
];

function getRandom(randArray) {
  var array = new Uint32Array(10);
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
}


function showrandom() {
  document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = wordings[getRandom(wordings)] + ' ' + wordings[getRandom(wordings)];
}
```

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of what you have tried so far?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto

Comment: Hey! I added my code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `)` It should be `document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = wordings[getRandom(wordings)] + ' ' + wordings[getRandom(wordings)];` Does this solve your problem?

Also as documentation shows [crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto) this method generates random integer values. As i understand from your code you are trying to derive index of the words inside `wordings` array from random number. To get indexes from random integers you could use modulo operation by `wordings.length` for each random number, but this approach needs to be investigated in terms of security issues.

the code would look like this:

```
var wordings = ['X',
    'I',
    'II'
];

function getRandom(randArray){
    var cryptoObj = window.crypto || window.msCrypto; // for IE 11
    var array = new Uint32Array(1);
    cryptoObj.getRandomValues(array);

    return array[0]%randArray.length;
}

function showrandom() {
    document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = wordings[getRandom(wordings)] + ' ' + wordings[getRandom(wordings)];
}
```

Comment: Hey Tornike. The missing ) was not the Problem, but the code solved my issue. I really thank you for your help and the documentation link.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It should be noted that the modulo operations leads to a not completely uniform output (early values are slightly more likely than late values). Using `Uint32Array` even though `Uint8Array` is usually enough reduces this effect. This shouldn't be a problem for most applications.

Answer (score 4):

The basic problem is that the `Math.random` returns values from 0 (*inclusive*) to 1 (*exclusive*), while the `window.crypto.getRandomValues` returns integers from 0 to the max 32 bit integer (*or whatever the max of the type of the array you pass in*).

So you need to to scale down the range of the `window.crypto` to the one in the `Math.random`

Something like

```js
function cryptoRandom(){
  // return a crypto generated number
  // between 0 and 1 (0 inclusive, 1 exclusive);
  // Mimics the Math.random function in range of results
  var array = new Uint32Array(1),
    max = Math.pow(2, 32), // normally the max is 2^32 -1 but we remove the -1
                           //  so that the max is exclusive
    randomValue = window.crypto.getRandomValues(array)[0] / max;

    return randomValue;
}

function getRandom(randArray) {
    return Math.floor(cryptoRandom() * randArray.length);
}
```

---

See https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9976493 for why using modulo `%` decreases the entropy of the random number